# Why is [[]]*10 the way to create a list of 10 empty lists in python instead of [[]*10]?

Tags: python, list

Why does `[[]]*10` make a list of ten empty lists? `[[]*10]` makes more sense to me.

Comment: I assume you meant `*` - feel free to undo my fix if not.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best explanation for you may be to look at `[1, 2] * 4`, which gives you `[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]`.  Multiplication with a list on the left makes copies of the elements of the list, not the list itself.

`[] * 10` makes ten copies of no elements whatsoever and gives you `[]`.

`[[]] * 10` gives you ten copies of `[]`, which is what you're looking for.

---

@blckknght points out, and it's worth emphasizing, that * repeats the elements of the list, but the elements themselves are not copied.

```
>>> X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> Y = [X] * 2
>>> Y
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Y now contains X itself twice, not two copies of X.

```
>>> Y[0] is X
True
>>> X[0] = 'a'
>>> Y
[['a', 2, 3, 4, 5], ['a', 2, 3, 4, 5]]
>>>
```

Comment: Indeed. Note that it would be extremely confusing if `[2 * 4]` gave you `[2, 2, 2, 2]` instead of `[8]`!

Comment: It's worth mentioning that "copies" is being used rather loosely here. There's no copying of the inner list being done, it's only the *reference* to the singular list that gets copied.

Answer (score 2):

The "better" way to create a list of 10 empty lists is to use a list comprehension

```
[[] for _ in range(10)]
```

`[[]] * 10` will create a list of 10 references to the **exact same list** and will lead to *interesting* behaviour

```
x = [[]] * 10
x[0].append(1)
print(x)
```

Outputs

```
[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

Why `[[] * 10]` doesn't behave as you want is covered by other answers

Answer (score 0):

Because `[] + [] == []` in Python.  So for your preferred syntax, the `*` operator is basically repeatedly adding `[]` to an empty list and getting another empty list back.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my explanations:

- `[[] * 10]` multiplies the values within the list, it gives `[[]]` because there are no values in the sublist, it's just an empty list, so as we all know `0 * 10` is `0`.
- `[[]] * 10` works because it multiples the value inside (as you know from above, I said it multiplies the values), here there are values it's the empty list `[]`, it multiples the `[[]]` ten times, so it multiplies the value ten times, so the value ten times would be: `[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]`

Answer (score -2):

1. `[[]]*10` :
   This mean you have 10 "list in list".

`[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[]]`

2.`[[]*10]`
This mean you have one list contain 10 list:

`[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]`

Comment: This is flat wrong. Have you tried the expressions you're discussing?